# Node.js webserver; Show contents of pgp asc file, not prompt for download

Tags: javascript, webserver, download

If you click this link: 
http://kenCode.de/kenCode.asc

Your browser tries to download the file instead of displaying the textual contents of it for api's and sites that need to just read it.

Mime types, right? Any idea how to tell my nodejs server to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Content-Type` header. If you get the "Content-Type" header set correctly, your browser will show the file rather than offer it for download.

With

```
curl --head http://kencode.de/kenCode.asc
```

I can see that content type is currently

```
Content-Type: application/pgp-signature
```

Browsers tend to offer to save Application file types, but show `text/plain` file types. 
Here is the [w3 documentation on Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_1_Text.html) that explains why "text/plain" is appropriate for this and why the character set is needed.

From the [node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html), it looks like the way to do so would be:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

If you can't modify the response directly in the file, you will have to configure your web server to do so for you. Web servers often map file types based on their extension when one is not supplied explicitly by the web application.  For example if you are using Apache server, you could add this to a *.htaccess* file to fix the problem:

```
AddType text/plain;charset=UTF-8 .asc
```

Comment: I can't edit the asc (pgp/gpg) file, it's my public sig key. I was hoping to just add a line or two of code to the server.js file on our node.js server.

Comment: If you click the link I posted above, it downloads the file. I don't want that. I want the browser to display the contents of that asc file...

Comment: If you get the "Content-Type" header set correctly, your browser will show the file rather than offer it for download.

Comment: we're not running apache and there is no .htaccess file in our root. the server.js file is the one that will have to be told what to do with the asc file...

Comment: It sounds like you have node.js configured to serve static files. It appears that there are several modules that can do this job and that they all have different ways of configuring the mime lookup.  It seems likely that it is getting the type from the global `/etc/mime.types` file, or has it hard coded.   You could try changing the mime type in `/etc/` or you could try renaming the file to a `.txt` extension.